# How can I update a whole collection in MongoDB and not document by document?

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, pymongo

I'm trying to update a collection in MongoDB after doing some analysis using pandas, this is my code:

```
client=MongoClient()
db=client.database
cll=db.collection

cursor=cll.find()
df=pd.DataFrame(list(cursor))

df['new_field'] = df['existing_field_A'].apply(lambda x: personalized_function(x))

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    _id=row['_id']
    new_value=row['new_field']
    cll.update_one({'_id':_id}, {'$set':{'new_field':new_value}})
```

The code works fine, but it takes to long. I would like to know if there's a better way to update my collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [unordered-bulk-write-operations](https://api.mongodb.com/python/2.7.2/examples/bulk.html#unordered-bulk-write-operations) and update all the documents in a single batch. This will improve the performance.

```
    bulk_update = cll.initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
       _id=row['_id']
       new_value=row['new_field']
       bulk_update.find({'_id':_id}).update_one({'$set'{'new_field':new_value}})
    bulk_update.execute()
```

Comment: Use colon (:) after $set keyword.